# SVG not diplaying on iPad and some Chrome

Tags: html, ipad, google-chrome, svg

I'm having issues embeddind an sgv document to my html.

Firefox displays ok in all computer and devides.

On iPad and PC Google Chrome v20 browsers the svg is not showing at all.

No error. No nothing.

Here is a jsfiddle of the code im pasting.

¿SVG is malformed?

http://jsfiddle.net/qysjC/2/

Thanks!

My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <title>blocks</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <svg version="1.1" id="rects" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
             width="948px" height="560px" viewBox="0 0 948 560" enable-background="new 0 0 948 560" xml:space="preserve">
        <symbol  id="L15" viewBox="-55.5 -10.5 111.001 21">
            <g>
                <polygon fill="#AA3333" points="0,-10.5 -55.5,-10.5 -55.5,10.5 55.5,10.5"/>
            </g>
        </symbol>
        <symbol  id="V15" viewBox="-55.5 -10.5 111.001 21">
            <g>
                <polygon fill="#3333AA" points="55.5,-10.5 -55.5,10.5 55.5,10.5"/>
            </g>
        </symbol>
        <use xlink:href="#L15"  width="111.001" height="21" x="0" y="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 474.0903 267.6709)" overflow="visible"/>
        <use xlink:href="#V15"  width="111.001" height="21" x="0" y="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 474.0903 292.2939)" overflow="visible"/>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a problem with the points here points="55.5,0,-10.5 -55.5,10.5 55.5,10.5", looks like a number is missing. Not sure if thats the problem you mention or just accident in the fiddle, but worth eliminating that.

Comment: I just corrected that and update the post and the fiddle. Thanks for pointing that out but still no luck.

Comment: @WhiteRaven Which versions are in question? Take a look at [browser compatibility with SVG](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg).

Comment: Google Chrome 20.0.1132.57 (Build oficial 145807) m